# Area Between Three Curves (No Upper Limit)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

I am asked to find the area between three curves for x greater than or equal to 0 (there is no upper limit.)

The equation for the functions are as follows: `y = 8x^2`, `y = 2x^2`, `y = 5 - 3x`.

Since there is no upper limit, I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you graph the functions to see what they look like?  Perhaps from there you can use theorems involving the area between two curves and partitioning your bounds accordingly.

Comment: The first step is locating the points where the curves intersect.  Note that the first two curves intersect at $(0,0)$, and the third "curve" is a downward sloping line.

Comment: Since the three curves already bound two finite regions, the apparent reason why you were told $x>0$ was to eliminate the region on the left of the $y$-axis and measure only the region on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the graphs and that will help. [Here they are](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qmuzljhwbk).

You need to find the area enclosed by the three curves. First, note intersection points. $$5-3x=8x^2\to x=\frac58\to (\frac58,\frac{25}{8})$$
$$5-3x=2x^2\to x=1\to(1,2)$$

Use area subtraction with integration to find the desired area:
[image]

The large triangle's area is the area bounded by $5-3x$ and the co-ordinate axes and therefore is $\frac12\cdot5\cdot\frac53=\frac{25}{6}$

Now, the desired area is $\frac{25}{6}-(A+B+C)$, so we simply need to find those three areas.

$C$ is very easy. It's simply another triangle, this time with vertices $(1,2), (1,0), (\frac 53, 0)$ and thus has area $\frac12\cdot2\cdot\frac23=\frac23$

$B$ is simply $$\int^{1}_{0}{2x^2dx}=\bigg[\frac23x^3\bigg]^{1}_{0}=\frac23$$ (It's the area under the curve between $x=0$ and the intercept point with $5-3x$)

$A$ is slightly more challenging. It is found by $$\int_{0}^{\frac58}{(5-3x)-8x^2dx}=\bigg[5x-\frac32x^2-\frac83x^3\bigg]^{\frac 58}_0=\frac{725}{384}$$

Thus the desired area is $\frac{25}{6}-(\frac23+\frac23+\frac{725}{384})=\frac{121}{128}$